# How to find the type for ethereum, provider, and contract

Tags: typescript, next.js, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I have this interface

```
interface IWeb3 {  
  ethereum?: MetaMaskInpageProvider;
  provider?: any;
  contract?: any;
};
```

I found the type for ethereum from `import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from "@metamask/providers"` but could not find others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install `ethers` library

```
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from "@metamask/providers";
import { Contract, providers } from "ethers";

interface IWeb3 {  
  ethereum?: MetaMaskInpageProvider;
  provider?: providers.Web3Provider;
  contract?: Contract;
};
```

Also to be able to use `window.ethereum`, I had to set this:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum: MetaMaskInpageProvider;
  }
}
```